# Starting and stopping Selenium as a Grunt task

Tags: selenium, gruntjs

I'd like to start Selenium as a Grunt task, run Cucumber, then stop Selenium after Cucumber exits.

I tried using grunt-shell to start Selenium. While this works, Selenium continues to run (as expected) and so Grunt hangs waiting for it to exit.

I also tried grunt-bgshell. This starts Selenium, but Grunt immediately starts Cucumber before Selenium is ready, and then Selenium continues to run after Grunt exits.

As a workaround for stopping Selenium I could probably use shell and curl to send the shutdown request to Selenium. But if there's a way to accomplish this without a workaround that would be even better.

### Update

See my answer below:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David Souther has written the grunt-selenium-launcher plugin which does exactly what I needed.

However, even after using the grunt-selenium-launcher plugin, Julien Biezeman helped me discover the best way to solve my problem was to launch selenium directly from my end to end tests in Cucumber using selenium-launcher.

I hope this helps someone!